# Foxit Reader Problems

Tags: pdf, foxitreader

I have two question

1. Why does this message "error:unexpected character, row:80, col:5" appear each time that I try to open a PDF with FOXIT READER (last version)?? I have on my computer UBUNTU 16.04. The message appears four times with an interval of two seconds and at the end of this four times my document appears.
2. Why can not I uninstall FOXIT READER from my computer with Ubuntu 16.04?  I tried to unistall FOXIT READER (to install again later) from the "Software Center" but it still there. It still there with the same message appearing four times before my document:

   ```
   error:unexpected character, row:80, col:5
   ```

Comment: How did you install Foxit Reader? The removing method depends on how you install it.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to install Foxit via their [official download site](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdaf-reader/), then the uninstall process is piece of cake.

Once you extract the setup file provided by official website, there will be an uninstaller located in the installation directory. You can simply run the file to bring up uninstall wizard.

By default, the main installation folder is `$HOME/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader`, where `$HOME` was your `/home` directory.